# Redireccionamiento Vista-Controlador en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de hacer un menú en html + php y quiero saber como traer una url para poder redireccionarlo a la vista correcta.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?Ayudaría bastante que coloques tú código, gracias y bienvenido a la comunidad

Comment: Bienvenido!...te invito dar el  [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea más afectiva, amplia y ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Usa un Router, (según la url, ejecutar acción),  puedes usar estas librerías

- [dispatch](https://github.com/noodlehaus/dispatch)
- [klein](https://github.com/klein/klein.php)
- [Ham](https://github.com/radiosilence/Ham)